# How to delete horizontal line from letter A in sketch?

Tags: text, sketch-app

I have an issue with text manipulation in `Sketch`. I want to change how letter A looks, so I need to delete the horizontal line so it will look like an upside down V.

I converted my text to Outline, but I still can't find a way to delete it.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hello Kobe, welcome to GDSE. Could you show us what you tried and why it didn't work. We aim for questions and answers that can help a lot of people, and right now your question is very specific. Could you rewrite it to make it more useful to more people. Thanks and keep contributing!

Comment: Have you also looked at an upside down V? Rotate by 180 degrees. Sometimes when I alter a type, it doesn't look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the first step is to creat text layer with A letter:
[image]

After convert the letter to Outlines:
[image]

Then press Edit icon on toolbar, it enable vector points on letter:
[image]

You should connect two pair of vector points as shown below
[image]

Just drag one point to another it will snap to each other automatically:
[image]

After connecting vector points to each other, press Enter to exit from Edit mode, and the result is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to manipulate the pathways in the same way you would in Illustrator or the like.

You manipulate the paths by using anchors, I have linked a video that shows how to manipulate a Letter A in the way you describe in Sketch.

[Manipulating letter A in Sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sg9LrrxlBpg&feature=youtu.be)